# How to prove propositional equality between a complicated expression and `True`?

Tags: idris, dependent-type, theorem-proving

I have some code that looks like this:

```hs
allLessThan : Ord t => (v1 : Vect n t) -> (v2 : Vect n t) -> Bool
allLessThan v1 v2 = all (\(x,y) => x < y) (zip v1 v2)

unravelIndexUnsafe : (order : ArrayOrder) ->
                     (shape : ArrayShape (S n)) ->
                     (position : Vect (S n) Nat) ->
                     Nat
unravelIndexUnsafe order shape position = ?someImplementation

unravelIndexSafe : (order : ArrayOrder) ->
                   (shape : ArrayShape (S n)) ->
                   (position : Vect (S n) Nat) ->
                   {auto 0 prfPositionValid : (allLessThan position shape) = True} ->
                   Nat
unravelIndexSafe order shape position = unravelIndexUnsafe order shape position

unravelIndex : (order : ArrayOrder) ->
               (shape : ArrayShape (S n)) ->
               (position : Vect (S n) Nat) ->
               Maybe Nat
unravelIndex order shape position =
  case allLessThan position shape of
    True => Just $ unravelIndexSafe order shape position
    False => Nothing
```

I omitted the implementation of `unravelIndexUnsafe` which I think is irrelevant to the question.

I get a type error in the definition of `unravelIndex`, saying that it can't find an implementation for `prfPositionValid` to use with `unravelIndexSafe`*.

This was surprising to me, because I am explicitly case splitting on `allLessThan position shape`, and only calling `unravelIndexSafe` in the `True` branch. I expected that Idris would be able to infer from this information that the proposition `(allLessThan position shape) = True` holds.

Is there a straightforward way to solve the problem? Maybe something I can explicitly construct and pass for the `prfPositionValid` implicit argument? Or is there an entirely different approach I should use here? Do I need to express `prfPositionValid` or `allLessThan` differently? Do I need to `rewrite` something?

* *More precisely, it can't find an implementation for this monstrous "fully-expanded" version of `prfPositionValid`*:

```
foldl (\acc, elem => acc && Delay (case block in allLessThan (S n) Nat (MkOrd (\{arg:354}, {arg:355} => compare arg arg) (\{arg:356}, {arg:357} => == (compare arg arg) LT) (\{arg:358}, {arg:359} => == (compare arg arg) GT) (\{arg:360}, {arg:361} => not (== (compare arg arg) GT)) (\{arg:362}, {arg:363} => not (== (compare arg arg) LT)) (\{arg:364}, {arg:365} => if == (compare arg arg) GT then x else y) (\{arg:366}, {arg:367} => if == (compare arg arg) LT then x else y)) shape position elem)) True (zipWith (\{__leftTupleSection:0}, {__infixTupleSection:0} => (__leftTupleSection, __infixTupleSection)) position shape) = True
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution: use decidable equality

The answer is to use "decidable equality", because Idris is not as smart as a human.

Note that the special `=` syntax is equivalent to the builtin operator `(===)`, which is equivalent to the type `Equal`. The constructor for `Equal` is `Refl`. In order to prove a proposition of the form `Equal a b`, Idris must be able to figure out that `a` and `b` are in fact the same thing (call it `c`). If you can invoke `Refl c` with type `Equal a b`, then you have proven `Equal a b`. Conversely, the *only* way to obtain an instance of `Equal a b` is by invoking `Refl c`.

Idris 2 cannot infer propositional equality by case-splitting. I, a human, know that we are trying to show that `allLessThan position shape` is propositionally equal to `True`. In Idris, this means we want to be able to write `Refl True`. Case-splitting on `allLessThan position shape` does result in a `Bool`, but this alone does not constitute an invocation of `Refl True` with type `Equal (allLessThan position shape) True`. Therefore case-splitting as in the original code is not sufficient for Idris to infer a proof of `Equal (allLessThan position shape) True`.

We know that `allLessThan position shape` is a *decidable* predicate, so we can use `decEq` to obtain the proof/implementation that we need. Therefore we can write `unravelIndex` as:

```hs
unravelIndex : (order : ArrayOrder) ->
               (shape : ArrayShape (S n)) ->
               (position : Vect (S n) Nat) ->
               Maybe Nat
unravelIndex order shape position =
  case decEq (allLessThan position shape) True of
    Yes proof => Just $ unravelIndexSafe order shape position
    No contra => Nothing
```

The `proof` in `Yes proof` is precisely the `Refl True` we were looking for, which implements `Equal (allLessThan position shape) True`. Therefore Idris will be able to infer a value for the `prfPositionValid` auto-implicit, because a value of the right type is available in scope.

You could also write `_` instead of `proof` and `contra`, because the proofs are not explicitly used in the code anywhere, so they don't need names.

### Refactoring

Note that this `allLessThan position shape` is somewhat ad-hoc. In particular, stating the conditions of the property requires the programmer to memorize a specific expression. However we would like to write a tidier API, in which the programmer can invoke a function `isPositionValidForShape` to check validity, and use a type `IndexValidForShape` to represent the "valid" state.

```hs
allLessThan : Ord t => (v1 : Vect n t) -> (v2 : Vect n t) -> Bool
allLessThan v1 v2 = all (\(x,y) => x < y) (zip v1 v2)

IndexValidForShape : (shape : ArrayShape ndim) ->
                     (position : ArrayIndex ndim) ->
                     Type
IndexValidForShape shape position =
  let isValid = allLessThan position shape
  in Equal isValid True

isIndexValidForShape : (shape : ArrayShape (S n)) ->
                       (position : ArrayIndex (S n)) ->
                       Dec (IndexValidForShape shape position)
isIndexValidForShape shape position =
  decEq (allLessThan position shape) True

unravelIndexUnsafe : (order : ArrayOrder) ->
                     (shape : ArrayShape (S n)) ->
                     (position : ArrayIndex (S n)) ->
                     Nat
unravelIndexUnsafe order shape position =
  sum $ zipWith (*) (strides order shape) position

unravelIndexSafe : (order : ArrayOrder) ->
                   (shape : ArrayShape (S n)) ->
                   (position : ArrayIndex (S n)) ->
                   {auto 0 prfIndexValid : IndexValidForShape shape position} ->
                   Nat
unravelIndexSafe order shape position =
  unravelIndexUnsafe order shape position

unravelIndex : (order : ArrayOrder) ->
               (shape : ArrayShape (S n)) ->
               (position : ArrayIndex (S n)) ->
               Maybe Nat
unravelIndex order shape position =
  case isIndexValidForShape shape position of
    Yes _ => Just $ unravelIndexSafe order shape position
    No _ => Nothing
```

Now, the end user don't have to know or care what exactly `IndexValidForShape` entails, or that you need to use `allLessThan` to check for it.

In fact, we can now change what it means for an index to be "valid", mostly without affecting downstream code user; maybe there are additional checks I want to put in place, that I only learn about after I find a logic bug.

Alternatively, it should be possible to re-design `IndexValidForShape` to be more "structural", wherein you inductively define a data type that represents the desired property. For example, refer to [`Data.Vect.Elem`](https://github.com/idris-lang/Idris2/blob/v0.4.0/libs/base/Data/Vect/Elem.idr#L12-L16) and its description in Chapter 9 of *Type-Driven Development*.

### Glossary

- decidable: "a property is decidable if you can always say whether the property holds for some specific values" (quoted from Type-Driven Development, page 245).
- `Dec`: The type representing the validity of a decidable property. Its constructors are:

  - `Yes : property -> Dec property` - the `property` holds.
  - `No : (property -> Void) -> Dec property` - the `property` is a contradiction.
- `DecEq`: The interface for data types for which equality can be determined as a decidable property.
- `decEq`: The method of `DecEq` that determines if two things are decidably equal. Its type is `DecEq t => (x1 : t) -> (x2 : t) -> Dec (Equal x1 x2)`.

### References & Further reading

- [*Type-Driven Development with Idris*](https://www.manning.com/books/type-driven-development-with-idris) (Edwin Brady, 2017, ISBN 9781617293023), especially section 9.1.5 which covers `Decidable.Equality`.